# Kolmogorov-Smirnov or a Chi-Square test for a distribution?

Tags: r, statistics

I used model fitting to fit the negative binomial distribution to my discrete data. As a final step it looks like I need to perform a Kolmogrov-Smirnov test to determine if the model fits the data well. All the references I could find talk about using the test for ***normally*** distributed ***continuous*** data. Can someone tell me if this can be done in R for data that is not normally distributed and discrete? (Even a chi-square test should do I'm guessing but please correct me if I'm wrong.)

**UPDATE:**

So I found that the `vcd` package contains a function `goodfit` that can be used for this purpose in the following way:

```
library(vcd)

# Define the data
data <- c(67, 81, 93, 65, 18, 44, 31, 103, 64, 19, 27, 57, 63, 25, 22, 150,
          31, 58, 93, 6, 86, 43, 17, 9, 78, 23, 75, 28, 37, 23, 108, 14, 137,
          69, 58, 81, 62, 25, 54, 57, 65, 72, 17, 22, 170, 95, 38, 33, 34, 68,
          38, 117, 28, 17, 19, 25, 24, 15, 103, 31, 33, 77, 38, 8, 48, 32, 48,
          26, 63, 16, 70, 87, 31, 36, 31, 38, 91, 117, 16, 40, 7, 26, 15, 89,
          67, 7, 39, 33, 58)

gf <- goodfit(data, type = "nbinomial", method = "MinChisq") 
plot(gf)
```

But after the `gf <- ...` step, R complains saying:

```
Warning messages:
1: In pnbinom(q, size, prob, lower.tail, log.p) : NaNs produced
2: In pnbinom(q, size, prob, lower.tail, log.p) : NaNs produced
3: In pnbinom(q, size, prob, lower.tail, log.p) : NaNs produced
```

and when I say `plot` it complains:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

I am not sure what is happening because if I set `data` to be the following:

```
data <- <- rnbinom(200, size = 1.5, prob = 0.8)
```

everything works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: plot(gf) works here (R 2.12.0, version 1.2-9 of vcd). Use options(warn=2,error=recover) to convert the warnings into errors and then start a browser on warn/error. At some point in the fitting process R is trying to make the NB 'prob' parameter negative ... f <- MASS::fitdistr(data,"negative binomial"); plot(table(data)/length(data)); curve(dnbinom(x,size=2.354,mu=50.8),from=1,to=170,n=170,add=TRUE,col=2) indicates that the data are too 'patchy' to fit a NB well.  Comparing $par in these two cases shows that you arrive at reasonably similar answers; the warnings are probably ignorable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A KS-Test is for continuous variables only, plus you have to fully specify the distribution you are testing against. If you still wanted to do it, it would look like this:

```
ks.test(data, pnbinom, size=100, prob=0.8)
```

It compares the empirical cumulative distribution function of `data` against the specified one (whether that makes sense probably depends on your data). You would have to choose parameters for `size` and `prob` based on theoretical considerations, the test is not valid if you estimate those parameters based on the data.

Your problem with `goodfit()` might have to do with your data, are you sure these are counts? `barplot(table(data))` does not look like it's approximately following a negative binomial distribution, compare, e.g., with `barplot(table(rnbinom(200, size = 1.5, prob = 0.8)))`

Finally, I'm not sure if the approach of doing a null-hypothesis test after fitting is appropriate. You may want to look into quantitative fit measures beyond / based on $\chi^2$ of which there are many (RMSEA, SRMR, ...).